# I'm trying to create SQLite database in android. But the app keeps freezing with a black screen whenever home activity is launched

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I am working on an android app. I am trying to create an sql database which stores all the info stored by a user. Currently i'm trying to just work on the onCreate method of Database handler. i want to create the database, and store the first entry into the database through the onCreate method itself.
And read the entries and display it out in the HomeActivity using a TextView.

The following is the code for the home activity of my application. I access a database handler class through this activity ( DBHandler ).

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {


    Button addCashButton,addExpenditureButton;
    private DBHandler dbHandler;
    TextView logText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Remove notification bar
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        dbHandler = new DBHandler(this,null,null,1);
        logText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.logText);

        addCashButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addCashButton);
        addExpenditureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addExpenditureButton);

        //Set Log
        logText.setText(dbHandler.showRecentLog(this));
    }



    //ADD CASH BUTTON CLICKED - Launch add cash activity
    public void launchAddCash(View view) {
        Intent addcash = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,AddCashActivity.class);
        startActivity(addcash);
    }
}
```

This is the DBHandler Class. **PLEASE IGNORE THE COMMENTED TEXT AS I HAVE COMMENTED OUT THE ACTUAL DATA AND JUST WORKING WITH TEST DATA TO GET MY CONCEPTS STRAIGHT**

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //Declaring Variables
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "test4db.db";
    //Table Name
    public static final String TABLE_ACCOUNT = "test1";
    //Column Names
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "_title";
    public static final String COLUMN_DESCRIPTION = "_description";
    public static final String COLUMN_DATE = "_date";
    public static final String COLUMN_TIME = "_time";
    public static final String COLUMN_CASH1 = "_cash1";
    public static final String COLUMN_CASH2 = "_cash2";
    public static final String COLUMN_CASH3 = "_cash3";
    public static final String COLUMN_CASH4 = "_cash4";
    public static final String COLUMN_CASH5 = "_cash5";
    public static final String COLUMN_CASH6 = "_cash6";
    public static final String COLUMN_CASH7 = "_cash7";
    public static final String COLUMN_CASH8 = "_cash8";
    public static final String COLUMN_CASH9 = "_cash9";
    public static final String COLUMN_CASH10 = "_cash10";
    public static final String COLUMN_AMOUNT = "_amount";
    Context context;
//    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();


    //Constructor
    public DBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context=context;
    }


    //ON CREATE METHOD
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


        //Test Query
        String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ACCOUNT + " (" + COLUMN_TITLE + " TEXT " + ");";

        db.execSQL(query);

        defaultLog(db);
        Toast.makeText(context,"onCreate",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }



    //DEFAULT LOG METHOD
    public void defaultLog(SQLiteDatabase db){


        //Test default
        String query = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_ACCOUNT + " (" + COLUMN_TITLE + ") VALUES (" + "\"TITLE\"" + ");";
        db.execSQL(query);
        Toast.makeText(context,"defaultLog",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    //ON UPGRADE METHOD
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ACCOUNT);
        onCreate(db);
        Toast.makeText(context,"onUpgrade",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    //Adding new log to the database
    public void addAmountLog(String title,String description,int amount,int np1,int np2, int np3, int np4, int np5, int np6, int np7, int np8, int np9, int np10,Context context){

        String query = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_ACCOUNT + " (" + COLUMN_TITLE + ", " + COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + ", "
                + COLUMN_CASH1 + ", "
                + COLUMN_CASH2 + ", "  + COLUMN_CASH3 + ", "  + COLUMN_CASH4 + ", "  + COLUMN_CASH5 + ", "
                + COLUMN_CASH6 + ", "  + COLUMN_CASH7 + ", "  + COLUMN_CASH8 + ", "  + COLUMN_CASH9 + ", "
                + COLUMN_CASH10 + ", "
                + COLUMN_AMOUNT + ") VALUES ("
                + title + ", " + description + ", " + amount + ", "
                + np1 + ", " + np2 + ", " + np3 + ", " + np4 + ", " + np5 + ", " + np6 + ", "
                + np7 + ", " + np8 + ", " + np9 + ", " + np10 + ");";

        Toast.makeText(context,title + " " + description,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    //Printing the log
    public String showRecentLog(Context context){
        String logString = "";
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ACCOUNT + " WHERE 1;";

        //Cursor
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        c.moveToFirst();

        while(!c.isAfterLast()){
            if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_title"))!=null){
                logString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_title"));
                logString += "\n";
            }
        }
        c.close();
        db.close();
        Toast.makeText(context,logString + "showRecentLog",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return logString;
    }
}
```

Comment: UI take more time to load information. Use asynctask  and UI Handler to load data in Background.

Comment: can you explain in a bit more detailed manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i dont know why this worked, but what i did was creating a class which stored all the data before adding it the sql table. I would like to research on why directly giving the values didn't work. I created the following class:

public class CurrentLog {

```
private int _id;
private String _title,_description;
private int _amount,_np1,_np2,_np3,_np4,_np5,_np6,_np7,_np8,_np9,_np10;
private long _balance;

public CurrentLog (){

}

public void set_id(int _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}

public void set_title(String _title) {
    this._title = _title;
}

public void set_description(String _description) {
    this._description = _description;
}

public void set_amount(int _amount, int balance) {
    this._amount = _amount;
    set_balance(_amount + balance);
}

public void set_np1(int _np1) {
    this._np1 = _np1;
}

public void set_np2(int _np2) {
    this._np2 = _np2;
}

public void set_np3(int _np3) {
    this._np3 = _np3;
}

public void set_np4(int _np4) {
    this._np4 = _np4;
}

public void set_np5(int _np5) {
    this._np5 = _np5;
}

public void set_np6(int _np6) {
    this._np6 = _np6;
}

public void set_np7(int _np7) {
    this._np7 = _np7;
}

public void set_np8(int _np8) {
    this._np8 = _np8;
}

public void set_np9(int _np9) {
    this._np9 = _np9;
}

public void set_np10(int _np10) {
    this._np10 = _np10;
}

public void set_balance(long _balance) {
    this._balance = _balance;
}

public long get_balance() {
    return _balance;
}

public int get_id() {
    return _id;
}

public String get_title() {
    return _title;
}

public String get_description() {
    return _description;
}

public int get_amount() {
    return _amount;
}

public int get_np1() {
    return _np1;
}

public int get_np2() {
    return _np2;
}

public int get_np3() {
    return _np3;
}

public int get_np4() {
    return _np4;
}

public int get_np5() {
    return _np5;
}

public int get_np6() {
    return _np6;
}

public int get_np7() {
    return _np7;
}

public int get_np8() {
    return _np8;
}

public int get_np9() {
    return _np9;
}

public int get_np10() {
    return _np10;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think changing this lines as below should solve your problem:-

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); //this should be 1st line

 this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
```

Comment: i dont think it has got to do something with this. its just an instance which needs to be passed to super class. the code has been working well, the problem started after adding the sql code